# Excel Range apply new NumberFormat

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range which I fill with Data and set a new NumberFormat, like that:

```
wkbActive = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
wksActive = (Excel.Worksheet)wkbActive.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range rngExample = wksActive.get_Range("A1");
rngExample.Value = "08.06.2015";
rngExample.NumberFormat = "ddd, d. M";
example.NumberFormat = "ddd, d. M";
```

The problem is that the new NumberFormat isn´t apply until I click into the cell.
Is there an "update" Method or sth for the Range?!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're setting the cell value to a `string` and this is not evaluated as a date until you click into the cell and press 'Enter'.

Excel stores dates as `double` which represents a time since 1900. You should set the `Value2` property to a `DateTime` per [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ad4d8d6.aspx):

```
rngExample.Value2 = new DateTime(2015, 6, 8);
rngExample.NumberFormat = "ddd, d. M";
```

Comment: I formatted my Dates within the .ToString() Methods like rngExample.ToString("d") to have a short representation of the Date. If I store the whole DateTime I got sth like this as the Value: 08.06.2015  20:52:30. How can I delete the last part "20:52:30"? It´s now correctly displayed, but I don´t want the hours mins and secs.

Comment: The `Date` property on `DateTime` has 00:00:00 as the time part - so something like `rngExample.Value2 = yourDateVariable.Date` should work.